# ONclick button, two expressions , getting errors in ELSE statement but works in if statement

Tags: javascript, php

In an onclick button I am passing two expressions separated by a comma. The buttons are part of a PHP `IF ELSE` statement. There is one button that appears in the `IF` part of the statement. It also passes two expressions. This button works well. Here is the `HTML` code for the first button:

```
<button id='Search' class='button btn' onclick='Search($tbl_id, $cid)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button>"
```

In the `ELSE` part of the statement I have another button that needs to also pass two expressions. However with this button I am getting a console error of

> `expected expression, got ','`.

This confuses me since the exact same `HTML` with two expressions works just fine in the `IF` part of the statement. I have narrowed down the error to being in the `HTML` by removing the `AJAX` and still getting the error here. Here is the `HTML` for the button in the `ELSE` portion of the statement.

```
<button id='largerSearch' class='button btn' onclick='largerSearch($tbl_id, $cid)'>Search for alternative <i class='seated-icon fas fa-globe'></i></button>"
```

If I remove the comma and remove on expression, then it works fine.

Why does the exact same `HTML` work and successfully pass two expressions in the IF portion of the statement and fail in the `ELSE` portion of the statement?

Comment: Maybe your $tbl_id or $cid could contains some escape chars when you jump the else part of your code,

Comment: Thanks but then why would it work in the IF statement and not the ELSE statement? The variables are the same. Plus when I delete the AJAX for testing, it still shows the same error. When that happens it isnt passing anything at all. Is there a good way to check just as a double check?

Comment: Can you print $tbl_id and $id elements to the text of button and also if your create a pen or jsfiddle I can help more.

Comment: I very much appreciate it. I actually just finally found it. One of the variables had no value which apparently throws this error. I dont know why this error would have been thrown when there is a variable with a blank value

Comment: Good to hear that. Bonne chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the variables passed is ultimately NULL or has no value then the console will thrown this error until you remove the empty variable.